# Last known location of a Device - geolocation dart package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocator

I am planning to use [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package on my Flutter project. I will take the last known location of the user periodically. But there is something that I couldnt find on the documentation. Does Android system periodically update the last known location on the device? If not, when does it update it? Is there any possibility of getting a null value?

Thank you.

Comment: The mentioned package has all the features and functions required to meet your requirements. I'm afraid that you haven't read the documentation properly.
The last known location could be null. You can listen to location updates via a stream.